# Uploading Files Using curl without user interaction

Tags: linux, curl, file-upload, virtual-machine, redhat

It doesn't give error but it doesn't work. I cannot see the file on the other server.
What should I write to upload file with curl with no user interaction?

```bash
$curl -k -F 'myfile=@/opt/test.txt' -H 'HTTP_AUTH_LOGIN:<destinationHostUsername>' -H 'HTTP_AUTH_PASSWD:<destinationHostPassword>' <destinationHostName>/
```

This html code below is the output when I run that curl command. I tried many lines but I couldn't do it. Can you guys can help me out?
(says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So I'm gonna write lots of things you don't have to read it
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test Page for the Apache HTTP Server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      /* <![CDATA[ */
      body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-family: sans-serif, helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      :link {
        color: #c00;
      }

      :visited {
        color: #c00;
      }

      a:hover {
        color: #f50;
      }

      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.6em 2em 0.4em;
        background-color: #900;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1.75em;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
      }

      h1 strong {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      hr {
        display: none;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 1em 5em;
      }

      .content-columns {
        /* Setting relative positioning allows for absolute positioning for sub-classes */
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 1em;
      }

      .content-column-left {
        /* Value for IE/Win; will be overwritten for other browsers */
        width: 47%;
        padding-right: 3%;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
      }

      .content-column-left hr {
        display: none;
      }

      .content-column-right {
        /* Values for IE/Win; will be overwritten for other browsers */
        width: 47%;
        padding-left: 3%;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
      }

      .content-columns>.content-column-left,
      .content-columns>.content-column-right {
        /* Non-IE/Win */
      }

      img {
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 2px;
      }

      a:hover img {
        border: 2px solid #f50;
      }

      /*]]>*/
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Red Hat Enterprise Linux <strong>Test Page</strong>
    </h1>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-middle">
        <p>This page is used to test the proper operation of the Apache HTTP server after it has been installed. If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at this site is working properly.</p>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="content-columns">
        <div class="content-column-left">
          <h2>If you are a member of the general public:</h2>
          <p>The fact that you are seeing this page indicates that the website you just visited is either experiencing problems, or is undergoing routine maintenance.</p>
          <p>If you would like to let the administrators of this website know that you've seen this page instead of the page you expected, you should send them e-mail. In general, mail sent to the name "webmaster" and directed to the website's domain should reach the appropriate person.</p>
          <p>For example, if you experienced problems while visiting www.example.com, you should send e-mail to "webmaster@example.com".</p>
          <p>For information on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, please visit the <a href="http://www.redhat.com/">Red Hat, Inc. website</a>. The documentation for Red Hat Enterprise Linux is <a href="http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/">available on the Red Hat, Inc. website</a>. </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="content-column-right">
          <h2>If you are the website administrator:</h2>
          <p>You may now add content to the directory <tt>/var/www/html/</tt>. Note that until you do so, people visiting your website will see this page, and not your content. To prevent this page from ever being used, follow the instructions in the file <tt>/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf</tt>. </p>
          <p>You are free to use the image below on web sites powered by the Apache HTTP Server:</p>
          <p align="center">
            <a href="http://httpd.apache.org/">
              <img src="/icons/apache_pb2.gif" alt="[ Powered by Apache ]" />
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the text starting with "If you are a member of the general public". It explains what's happening.

Comment: The URL needs to be a script that processes the file upload. You're just posting to the root URL of the website.